# Match dictionaries using nested comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying match a dictionary with predefined raid configurations with a dictionary that contains the physical disk layout.

```
raid_config = 
{ 'server1': [{'name' : 'data', 'disks' : 3, 'block' : 300}],
  'server2': [{'name' : 'data', 'disks' : 8, 'block' : 2200}],
  'server3': [{'name' : 'data', 'disks' : 2, 'block' : 300}, {'name' : 'data2', 'disks' : 2, 'block' : 300}, {'name' : 'data3', 'disks' : 2, 'block' : 1800},  {'name' : 'data', 'disks' : 8, 'block' : 300}],
  'server4': [{'name' : 'data', 'disks' : 3, 'block' : 300}, {{'name' : 'data2', 'disks' : 8, 'block' : 880}]
}
```

```
disks =
{300: ['bay0', 'bay1', bay10'], 880: ['bay2', 'bay3', 'bay4', 'bay5', 'bay6', 'bay7', 'bay8', 'bay9']}
```

Previously I wrote a comprehension that summed the disk sizes for the raid configs and for the physical disks and matched those. That doesn't work anymore since that would result in multiple matches for different layouts.

```
print({sum(v['disks']*v['size'] for v in vs) : k for k, vs in raid_config.items()}.get(sum(k*v for k,v in {k : len(v) for k,v in disks.items()}.items())))
-->
server4
```

I'm struggling to come up with a minimalistic approach to get an exact match. What would be the best approach here?

Comment: It seems that `disks` is a set.Right?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA It's a dict with the size as key and the value is a list

Comment: This does not really answer the question, but I think it's the right time to build a proper model instead of using such dictionaries with implicit relations between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself but I'm sure it can be done a little neater so input is still welcome.

```
configs = {}

for k, v in raid_config.items():
  configs[k] = {}
  for d in v:
    if d.get('size') in configs[k]:
      configs[k][d.get('size')] += d.get('disks') 
    else:
      configs[k][d.get('size')] = d.get('disks')
```

^-- pretty sure that can be done in a single line

Which results in:

```
{'server1': {300: 3}, 'server2': {2200: 8}, 'server3': {300: 12, 1800: 2},'server4': {300: 3, 880: 8}}
```

Find the matching config:

```
for k,v in configs.items():
  if disks == v:
    print(k)
```

Result:
`server4`